# Can we bind a generic list of structures to GridView in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding, struct

I was unable to find any resources that would help answer if we can do a bind of a generic List of structures in C#/ASP.NET. For instance, following is my struct definition:

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public string first_name;
    public string last_name;
} 

public class MyClass
{
    MyStruct myStruct;
    List<MyStruct> structList;

    public MyClass()
    {
        structList = new List<MyStruct>();
        myStruct.first_name = "aaa";
        myStruct.last_name = "bbb";
        structList.Add(myStruct);
    }

    public List<MyStruct> returnStruct()
    {
        return structList;
    }
}

protected void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    List<MyStruct> myStructList = myClass.returnStruct();
    myGridView.DataSource = myStructList;
    myGridView.DataBind();

}
```

Following is the error I get: The data source for GridView with id 'myGridView' did not have any properties or attributes from which to generate columns.  Ensure that your data source has content.

**Edit**: I replaced the struct with a class with the following definition and the binding succeeded.

```
public class myStructClass
{
    public string first_name {get; set}
    public string last_name  {get; set}

    public myStructClass()
    {
    }
}
```

So, I'm either doing something wrong with the Struct or C# doesn't support List of struct for binding.

Comment: How is the gridview control defined on the page? Did you include LayoutTemplate, Item Template, or EmptyDataTemplate?

Comment: Are you using a DataGridView or the Telerik GridView ?

Comment: @Connie - Hey Connie, not sure I get your question. Nothing fancy, I just pulled the asp:GridView server control onto the asp.net page, created a new class with a struct and class def (as above) and tried to bind.

Comment: @JamesDev -  James, its a plain old asp.net DataGridView.

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong. It is just binding which doesn't support objects that don't have any properties. This is because binding works only on properties, not fields. But that should not be a problem, structs can contain properties.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. I tested the struct with properties and it worked !